# How can I avoid selected text still being highlighted after text area is disabled? (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, highlight, lost-focus

Weird issue in Chrome 83 (works fine in FF 78):

1. I select text in a text area --> it gets highlighted
2. I click somewhere else --> the text area loses its focus, selected text is still highlighted
3. the text area is disabled (by javascript) --> selected text still remains highlighted - weird!

Setting the selection range to zero doesn't help. Setting user-select to none doesn't help either. Nor does clearing the window's / document's selection via javascript have any effect. The text highlighted persists. Only thing that helps: Select other text on that web page.

Is this a bug? Can I do anything to actively remove the text selection / text highlight by using css / javascript?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Make a jsfiddle of it

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do `selection.removeAllRanges()` or `selection.empty()`, depending on how old the browser is. I'm using the `mouseout` event here because for me, at least, clicking outside of the textarea clears the selection regardless.

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    document.getElementById('test').disabled = true;
    var sel = window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() : document.selection;
    if (sel) {
        if (sel.removeAllRanges) {
            sel.removeAllRanges();
        } else if (sel.empty) {
            sel.empty();
        }
     }
});
```

```html
<textarea id="test"></textarea>
```